# Why do some x64 compilers not inline fmin/fminf?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, min, icx

I have been benchmarking some fast numerical code on various compilers recently and was struck by a systematic variation in the speed with certain compilers at maximum optimisation -O2 and AVX/AVX2 code generation. I have narrowed some of it down to a curious behaviour than sets the fastest code generators apart from the rest.

Namely that with AVX code generation enabled and -O2 Clang and ICX will inline calls to `fminf/fmin` as `minss` whereas the rest of the pack GCC, ICC and MSVC stubbornly continue to `call fminf`. They all quite happily inline `fabsf/fabs` OK.

The code for an MRE is below and if I have done it right this is a link to it on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/acxKsjWEW) where you can try it on various compilers. Clang and Intel's ICX seem to inline it going as far back as I could find compilers to test.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  float y, x = 2.0;
  y = 10*rand()-5;
  y = fabs(y);
  if (x < y) y = x;
  printf("%g", y);
  y = 10 * rand();
  y = fminf(x,y);
  printf("%g", y);
}
```

A summary table is as follows:

| Compiler | inline `fminf` |
| --- | --- |
| GCC 13.2 | no |
| ICC latest | no |
| MSVC 2022 x64 | no |
| CLANG 17.0.1 | yes |
| ICX | yes |

`fmin` and `fmax` appear in quite a lot of numerical optimisation code so the slow down can be fairly significant. It can be worked around by defining macros `FMIN` and `FMAX` once you know. It would be nice if the other compilers inlined it though.

I can't think of any reason why this particular optimisation is missing in some compilers... does anyone have an explanation? `fabs` is a more complex case and that does inline in all of them.

Comment: In benchmarking, good to avoid any potential _undefined behavior_ (UB) of `int` overflow in `10*rand()`.  Consider `y = rand()-5;` and `y = rand();`.

Comment: "`fabs` is a more complex case " --> No.  I'd say simpler as it deals with 1 bit (just have to clear the sign bit) as compared to `fmin()` which deals with 2*64 bits.

Comment: On an unrelated note, unless you have a specific requirement to use `float`, don't use it. Use `double` instead.

Comment: @Martin Brown, Why compare `double fabs(double)` usage to `float fminf(float, float)`?  Suggest to make both functions `double` or both `float` for a better compare.

Comment: My guess would be that compiler authors simply haven't gotten around optimizing those calls yet.

Comment: @chux My mistake! Typing it into Godbolt I was thinking in Fortran when I used rand() (where it is a real on 0.0-1.0) . It is only there to force the compiler to generate the explicit comparison code. I should have left it as just rand(). fabs is just a careless typo on my part. Although looking at it in Godbolt it has taken the overloaded version of absf that matches the float argument type.

Comment: @Martin Brown, since the higher level goal is to improve time performance, consider another question that poses the real code problem. Optimizing `fminf()` may only be only one of multiple ways to improve.

Answer (score 4):

The basic issue is that the `minss` instruction does not do the same thing as the `fminf` function if the second operand is NaN, so a call to `fminf` cannot be safely replaced by (just) that instruction.

You can use `-ffast-math` to enable optimizations that may not be strictly IEEE correct (particularly in the presence of NaNs like this).

Comment: I take your point about the asymmetric Nan behaviour of `minss` being suboptimal and different to `fminf`. OTOH in a lot of use cases one of the two arguments can be shown to be not a Nan at compile time so it should not really inhibit generating `minss` in those cases. Typically things like finding the minimum or maximum over a vector or limiting the extent of some variable to the constant range that an expansion is valid for. I'd particularly like to find a way of getting rid of `fmin` calls in MS C/C++.  MS implementation of `fmin` is rather sluggish.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite simple. Some compilers need additional flags to do fast math. For example gcc `-ffast_math` .It disables many IEEE features + does not set errno.

Your example (extended a bit) [compiled by GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/4jnodMheh)

I do not use other compilers so cant tell what command line options you need to pass

Comment: Thanks for that refinement. If anyone knows of a compiler option for MS C/C++ that will allow this optimisation then I'd be very happy (/fp:fast and inline any /Ob2 don't). I generally do compile my stuff on GCC/Clang with -ffast-math but I still struggle to get it competitive in speed with either of MS C 2022 or Intel C ICX (fastest of all).